# What would be the time complexity of this code?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

What would be the time complexity of this code?

```
i = n;
  while(i > 1) {
    j = i;
    while (j < n) {
      k = 0;
      while (k < n) {
        k = k + 2;
      }
      j = j * 2;
    }
    i = i / 2;
  }
```

I tried analyzing this code and got a complexity of `Log^2n * n` I rewrote the code in a for loop format to make it easier to see which came out like this.

```
for (i = n; i > 1; i = i / 2) // log2n + 1
  {
    for(j = i; j < n; j = j * 2) // log2n + 1
    {
      for (k = 0; k < n; k = k + 2)  // n + 1 times
      {
          cout << "I = " << i << " J = " << j << " and K = " << k << endl;
      }
      cout << endl;
    }
  }
```

Is that correct? If not, why? I am new to algorithms and trying to understand but don't know where else to ask, sorry.

Comment: Isn't it your instructor's job to decide whether your homework is correct or not?

Comment: It is but I am trying to understand outside of the class. Is there any harm in getting help outside of the class if I have done what I can and understand the code's complexity since it's not an easy subject?

Comment: If we tell you that your solution is not correct and how to fix it, and you use that to get a better grade than you've earned on your assignment, it's an issue. First, you're cheating to get a better grade. Second, you're not learning what you should from the class, and your instructor isn't getting the feedback that the homework is supposed to provide.

Comment: This is exam practice and I am not getting graded on it. I have watched multiple videos outside of class on Youtube from great instructors about the subject before asking for help for someone because I am unsure. I understand you can be (and are most likely) a great programmer but everyone has to start somewhere. I'm sure you did not get everywhere in life knowing everything about programming. I ask for help from people who know the subject better than I do and I cannot just have contact with my instructor at all times.

Comment: @Ken It's not cheating if he's putting in effort to understand the answer; and as for the feedback that's the professor's problem, not his

Comment: @0x499602D2 Thank you! I appreciate your help from the other night too! I understand it's school work but I cannot afford a tutor. I have to use online resources to understand one of the harder courses in the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your answer is correct. The variable *i* is halved at every step, making the outer loop *O(log n)*. *j* doubles at every step, making that loop *O(log n)*, and the innermost *k* loop increases linearly, making that loop *O(n)*. Multiplying together gives *O(n log² n)*.

Comment: Thank you again! That was my initial thought. I appreciate the help again. I'm sorry for asking stupid questions.

Comment: @ThatOne You're welcome. And this is not a stupid question. A question like this will help people in the future who are new to this subject.